# cairoDevice package  under WIndows7

Tags: r

When I'm trying to load the R cairoDevice package under Windows7 I receive the message:

```
not a win32 program
```

Is there a solution?

Apostolos

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a 64-bit windows system and I haven't had any problems in Rstudio with the *cairoDevice* library. I have had some issues with the *Cairo* not working with symbols but the *cairoDevice* solved that issue for me.

My suggestion is that you try:

- Install/re-install the GTK+ package - try with the [Gimp installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-win/)
- Try with [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) that seems very stable
- See if it makes any difference in 32-bit vs 64-bit versions of R

### Update

I recently revisited the cairoDevice and the Cairo packages. The Cairo package seems actually more reliable than the cairoDevice package once you get the right resolution, and point size parameters. I wrote a blog post about this: http://gforge.se/2013/02/exporting-nice-plots-in-r/